# How to append array elements to div?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, string, dom

I have been trying to change so I get the push from a input form but having no luck.

```
<form id="myform">
    <input id="type" type="text" name="input">
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Add number</button>
</form>
<br>
<div id="box"; style="border:1px solid black;width:150px;height:150px;overflow:auto">
</div>
<script>
    var number= [];
    function myFunction()
    {
        number.push= document.getElementById("type").value;
        var x=document.getElementById("box");
        x.innerHTML=number.join('<br/>');
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace:

```
var x = document.getElementById("demo");
```

With:

```
var x = document.getElementById("box");
```

And if you want to convert your array into string, you can use the javascript function `join()`:

```
x.innerHTML = number.join(',');
// Or
x.innerHTML = number.toString();
```

Is this what you want?

Comment: oh thanks you that solved the problem i was gunna leave as array cause i wanted to add a for loop so each input will be put on a new line just not sure how to add it in yet, For (int i=o, i<numbers.lenght;i++){ number display +=numbers(i)="<br>;

Comment: You want each item on a new line right? No need of `for` loop. Just replace: `x.innerHTML = number.join(',');` with `x.innerHTML = number.join('<br />');`. Simple.

Comment: ok so my heads about to explode here lets say i want to get the push number from input form i have been trying to link it together for hours but have had no luck i have deleted most my efforts just left the input bo any help please

Comment: You can use this na? `number.push(document.myform.input.value)`

Comment: makes sense but not working could i be missing quuotation marks or something simple

Comment: Yeah, else do one thing. Give an `ID` for the `input` and use `document.getElementById('id').value`. It should surely work! :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert array, like:

```
x.innerHTML=number.join(",");
```

And:

```
var x = document.getElementById("box");
```

Comment: Array has toString() capability so no need.

Comment: `toString` is called implicitly on assignment to a string property, `join` is only needed if a format other than the default is required.

Comment: Best way is to check it out with a live evaluator. Feel guilty as haven't got around to fixing some of the functionality (and maybe better ones out there by now), but I still find it helpful to click a toolbar button to get a live HTML Editor to work with any time in Ted's https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/extension-developer/ extension.

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr = [];

function func () {
  arr.push('5');
  document.getElementById('box').innerHTML = arr.toString();
}
```

Comment: There is no need to call `toString`, assignment to a string property calls `toString` implicitly.